# Rails 3 Two Applications on Different Domains (same ip) with Apache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, subdomain, passenger

I deployed using phusion passenger on apache2 intially with just my single Rails application onto a domain, say `bar.com`. Now I wish to push an additional app I recently created to a subdomain on the bar domain, say `foo.bar.com`. I was a little confused about how I should setup the virtualhosts in the `httpd.conf` file to allow for this setup. I setup my DNS through godaddy so that the new subdomain would point to the same ip address as the initial domain (they're both residing on the same server).

Here's the VirtualHosts in my httpd.conf file (notice the two document roots points to different applications):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName bar.com
  ServerAlias www.bar.com
  DocumentRoot /home/me/app1/public
  <Directory /home/me/app1/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.bar.com
  ServerAlias foo.bar.com www.foo.bar.com
  DocumentRoot /home/me/app2/public
  <Directory /home/me/app2/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With this setup I can navigate to `www.bar.com` or `bar.com` but it seems the subdomain doesn't work, navigating to `foo.bar.com` leads me to this page:

> ### **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at foo.bar.com Port 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involved a couple of steps. Firstly I moved my virtualhosts outside of my httpd.conf file and create to new files under the sites-available folder each named after the corresponding domain `bar.com` and `foo.bar.com`. Next I had to add each site to sites-enabled by running the apache command `sudo a2ensite`. Finally I had to call the command `sudo service apache2 reload`. It's important that each command was run with admin access or else it didn't work.

Also worth mentioning, browsers like Firefox like to cache old website domain name data so if the url foo.bar.com previously wasn't working and you resolve the problem it will still appear to not work until you clear your cache.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to restart apache after adding the second virtual host?

Comment: Yes I did, and just FYI this really isn't an answer - instead it should be a comment to the question. :)